# Integration of MobileFirst Application onto BlueMix

Tags: migration, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a set of applications that have been developed by IBM using MobileFirst so it uses Worklight servers and adapters within the application.

I have been requested to investigate the possibilities of taking a hybrid mobile application developed on worklight and trying to migrate it onto something like IBM's BlueMix.

I was hoping someone could provide me with some insight as to how much work may be involved or if this task is even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1, you can run your MobileFirst Server on IBM Containers, a technology powered by IBM Bluemix... you can read more about it here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/

You can start by evaluating it: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/evaluate/

And later, assuming you are an IBM MobileFirst Platform customer, migrate your existing project and applications to it: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/

You will also want to experiment with MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 beta: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/beta/

v8.0 beta also provides an all-new approach for running on Bluemix: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/ibm-containers/using-mobile-foundation/

Using 8.0 will require some migration effort, but it'll be worth it. :)

Comment: We are using MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0

In doing what you suggested is it possible to eliminate the use of Worklight servers all together?

Comment: You do not eliminate it at all. You are only moving it to the cloud. You can do this only with v7.1 and above.

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear, we want to try and eliminate the use of worklight servers. I believe what you suggested is moving a MobileFirst project onto bluemix. That being said, do you feel it would be possible to integrate some of the code to run on bluemix entirely and not depend on Worklight at all or would it be easier to re write the application at that point? Sorry if I am not making complete sense, my experience / knowledge with either of these platforms is limited.

Comment: You cannot use features of MobileFirst without the server.

Comment: Ok so essentially you're telling me we would be better off to re write the application if we want to eliminate Worklight server dependencies?

Comment: If you don't want to use worklight anymore, don't use worklight...understand that as you will. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me some feedback with our issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could migrate your adapters and the app integrated with the MFP SDk as is and move it to Bluemix using MFP 7.1 on containers. The effort is minimal - say 2 days. Based on your comments above, If you want to ditch all that and remove worklight out of the equation all altogether, you will have to hand roll all that functionality that worklight was providing to you and of course maintain it yourself. Then this ceases to be a worklight question :) and the effort is certainly more than couple of days.